# iptables rule for incoming from certain ip and port

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I have 2 servers, one for web requests (I named it the `web`) and another one is for database (I named it the `db`). Both servers are CentOS 7.

I want to make these rules in `iptables`:

- all request to `db` server should be blocked (all IPs on all ports);
- just `web` server (`y.y.y.y`) can access the `db` server on ports `5432` and `6379`;
- just a static ip (`x.x.x.x`) can access port `22`.

So I wrote these rules but I'm not sure they are correct

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -s y.y.y.y -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6379 -s y.y.y.y -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s x.x.x.x -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While those rules looks correct (assuming they go to the `db` server`), you're
missing an important rule, which is:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Without that rule, and with the default `INPUT` policy as `DROP`, your `db` server itself won't be able to access the network, for example to install upgrades or `ping`/`traceroute` reachability checks, etc.

So a complete `iptables` ruleset should be

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -s y.y.y.y -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6379 -s y.y.y.y -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s x.x.x.x -j ACCEPT
```

Please make sure not to do `iptables -P INPUT DROP` via `ssh` as it will lock you out of your server.

Comment: Thank you, so should I use my rules plus your rule ?

Comment: @MajAfy I've update my answer with full ruleset.